# Proposition 5.3 in Neukirch's algebraic number theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have a question in Neukirch's algebraic number theory (Proposition 5.3)

In last 2 lines, he define group homomorphism from the ''units of valuation ring'' to the 'units of residue field'.

Why the $(q-1)$th roots of unity bijectively mapped onto 'units of residue field'?

I also feel a bit confused: if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are mapped to same class, then does it mean $u_1-u_2 \in p$ or $u_1u_2^{-1} \in p$, where $p$ is the maximal ideal? [I think it should be first one by the definition of quotient ring. But the proposition says the decomposition is multiplication, not addition.]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid relying on images to convey information not otherwise available in your post. [Here is an explanation of why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: In answer to your 'bit confused' comment: If $u_1u_2^{-1}\in p$, then $p$ would contain a unit, and so would be the whole ring - so that's out (assuming your $u_k$ are units). Rather $u_1u_2^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, hence $u_1u_2^{-1}\in U^{(1)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reduction is a mapping of *multiplicative* groups.  Think of the simplest case, with the $p$-adic integers: $\mathbf Z_p^\times \to (\mathbf Z_p/p\mathbf Z_p)^\times$ by $u \mapsto u \bmod p\mathbf Z_p$.  The kernel is $1 + p\mathbf Z_p$, and $u \equiv v \bmod p\mathbf Z_p$ for *units* $u, v \in \mathbf Z_p^\times$ if and only if $u - v \in p\mathbf Z_p$, which can be written as a multiplicative coset relation: $u/v \in 1 + p\mathbf Z_p$. That would not be true if we weren't working with units.

If you don't see why the $(q-1)$-th roots of unity map bijective to the residue field, make sure to understand that in the simplest case of $\mathbf Z_p^\times$ first: why does $\mathbf Z_p^\times$ contain $(p-1)$-th roots of unity, and why do they reduce mod $p$ to the different elements of $(\mathbf Z_p/p\mathbf Z_p)^\times$?  (Hint: Think of Hensel's lemma for $x^{p-1}-1$.)